# Options for working with a Visual C++ 6 project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2013, visual-c++-6

Just my luck, I have to work with a project using MFC which was coded 14 years ago. 
The good news is that once I have compiled the code and can see what the GUI is doing I am done with it and can go back to Qt. 
The bad news is that the project is humongous and whoever coded it seems to have "taken advantage" of all the bad programming allowed in VC++ 6. A couple hundred mistakes in poorly written code are separating me from a successful build.
Right now I have Visual Studio 2013 Professional (got it for free since I am a computer science student) and obviously it hates that old code as much as I do. All the searches I've done have brought up questions from a few years ago (probably when MFC was still relevant). What exactly can I do now, in 2014, apart from fixing the couple hundred mistakes? Is there a way a computer science student could get Visual C++ 6 or anything that would make that code compile in this day and age?

Comment: So is your main goal to try to refactor the old code to bring it up to C++11 standards? Or to find a compiler that will build the old code?

Comment: If you're not going to detail any of these "mistakes" then the only possible answer is to fix them one by one. It's not obvious to me why a valid project in VC++6 would fail to compile with the latest compiler that includes MFC.

Comment: share the errors. They're probably a combination of the for-scope and some deprecated str* functions. You can maintain MFC apps in VS 2013 and in fact you can even do so without making a face like the dog has pooped under your desk. Really.

Answer (score 1):

A couple hundred errors in a "humongous" program is no big deal: Many of them probably have a common cause. You can plow through and fix them, or you can probably find a VC++6 available on Ebay.

Answer (score 0):

You suck it up buttercup and get to grips with VC6 (which is still the best of all the Visual Studio versions) and can be installed on Windows 7 with a patch (google for it).

Or you try [something like this.....](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/winmigrate-walkthrough.html) and [use this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/).

Comment: Sadly those links you sent are almost as out-dated as MFC itself.